# counting number of employees connected to other nodes throw multiple relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have some employees who have conflict in positions, depending on their contract they are working as Labors but in the field they are working as drivers, in my database I am recording every position source as relationship between an employ node and role node. what I am trying to figure out is, how should I query the count of employ with no conflict between both relationship, and if there is conflict I want to count the employees distinctly depending on the role of each relationship, for example:
I have the following:

- 3 employee have driver contract and working as drivers, so their both relationship connected to the driver node.
- 4 employee have labor contract and working as drivers, so one relationship connect to the labor node and the other connected to driver node.
- 10 employee have labor contract and working as labor, so their both relationship connected to the labor node.

[Look at the model here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UhYz.png)

`MATCH (m2)<-[r2 {source:"operation"}]-(e:Employee)-[r1 {source:"contract"}]->(m1) RETURN distinct m1.name as contract_position, m2.name as operation_position, count(e)`

I tried this and it did almost what I want but if I had more than two relationship (more than two sources), I don't think it will work.

keep in mind that I have more roles than theses two roles and I would like to get a nice understanding between what in paper and what in operation.
**PS: I am just starting to learn about graph databases and neo4j, so give some slack :)**

Comment: we gonna give you some slack if you at least show us some effort of what you've tried so far.

Comment: I added some code